# Why does an instance constructor point to top most function constructor object?

Tags: javascript

I am reading couple of books about JavaScript to enhance my skills on it.

I encountered a problem with constructor of a object as I expected it to give me a function that generated an object with a call with `new` keyword, however it gave me a top-level function whose prototype is `Object`.

Please look at this code

```
var Top = function() {
    this.name = 'Top';
};

var Middle = function() {
    this.name = 'Middle';
}

var Bottom = function() {
    this.name = 'Bottom';

}

Middle.prototype = new Top();
Bottom.prototype = new Middle();

btm = new Bottom();

// I understand this, it gives me instance of Middle
console.log(Bottom.prototype);

// I don't understand this, I expected to see the same
console.log(btm.constructor.prototype);
```

Why does `btm.constructor` point to `Top` it's weird to me and I want to understand such behavior. How can I access Middle > Name only through the `btm` instance?

Comment: Maybe [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#object.prototype) helps you?

Comment: I understood, it is needed to manually specify a constructor for each prototype. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you destroyed the original `.constructor` property when you did this:

```
Bottom.prototype = new Middle();
```

Only the default `.prototype` object that comes on the function gets the automatic `.constructor` property that points back to the function.

If you overwrite it, you need to manually put it back.

```
console.log(Bottom.prototype.constructor === Bottom); // true

Bottom.prototype = new Middle();

console.log(Bottom.prototype.constructor === Bottom); // false

Bottom.prototype.constructor = Bottom;

console.log(Bottom.prototype.constructor === Bottom); // true
```

Or in newer browsers, use `Object.defineProperty()`.

```
Object.defineProperty(Bottom.prototype, "constructor", {
    value: Bottom,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll read your answer many times until I understand this compeletly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the constructor on the bottom class:

```
Bottom.prototype.constructor = Bottom;
```